# Understanding basic concepts of CUDA through vector addition

Tags: performance, vector, cuda, addition

I'm opening this topic because I noticed strange behavior in the output of my code, while trying to gain insight about some basic concepts in CUDA like speed vs number of blocks/threads etc...  Any help would be appreciated!

First of all, here are some specs of my graphic card:
Name: GeForce 8600M GT
Multiprocessor count: 4
Max threads per block: 512
Max grid dimensions: (65535, 65535, 1)

I was playing with the following simple code. It fills 3 arrays of length N with 1s and computes the sum. The sum is obviously predictable and equals 3N.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArgumentParser.h"

//using namespace std;

__global__ void addVector(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *N){
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid<*N) {
        d[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid] + c[tid];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Handy way to pass command-line arguments.
    ArgumentParser parser(argc, argv);
    int nblocks = parser("-nblocks").asInt(1);
    int nthreads = parser("-nthreads").asInt(1);

    //Defining arrays on host.
    int N = 100000;
    int a[N];
    int b[N];
    int c[N];
    int d[N];

    //Pointers to the arrays that will go to the device.
    int *dev_a;
    int *dev_b;
    int *dev_c;
    int *dev_d;
    int *dev_N;

    //Filling up a, b, and c.
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        a[i] = 1;
        b[i] = 1;
        c[i] = 1;
    } 

    //Modifying the memory adress of dev_x so that dev_x is on the device and //
    //the proper memory size is reserved for it.  
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_d, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_N, sizeof(int));

    //Copying the content of a/b/c and N to from the host to the device.
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_N, &N, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Initializing the cuda timers.
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start); 
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord (start, 0);

    //Executing the kernel.
    addVector<<<nblocks, nthreads>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, dev_d, dev_N);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float time;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf ("CUDA time: %3.5f s\n", time/1000);

    //Copying the result from device to host.
    cudaMemcpy(d, dev_d, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Freeing the memory allocated on the GPU
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_d);
    cudaFree(dev_N);

    //Checking the predictable result.
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        sum += d[i];
    }
    printf("Result of the sum: %d. It should be: %d.\n", sum, 3*N);
}
```

**Question 1:**
When I compile the code and type:

```
./addArrayCuda -nblocks 1 -nthreads 1
```

I get as an answer:

```
Result of the sum: -642264408. It should be: 300000.
```

This seems reasonable. I use a single block with a single thread. Only the first element of each array will be added. The rest of the elements being some random values, they add up to something unpredictable. It should be that nblocks * nthreads >= N. So let's try:

```
./addArrayCuda -nblocks 3125 -nthreads 32
```

The output is:

```
Result of the sum: 300000. It should be: 300000.
```

This makes sense. 3125 * 32 = 100000 = N. Until here, everything is fine. However if I rerun the previous command (with nblocks = nthreads = 1) **without recompiling** I get:

```
./addArrayCuda -nblocks 1 -nthreads 1
Result of the sum: 300000. It should be: 300000.
```

***What happened??***

**Question 2:**
This question is about the relationship between nblocks/nthreads vs speed of execution. I'm aware that this question might not make too much sense if a problem in the code explains **Question 1**, but let me still ask it. I've looked at the execution time of the code (average over 5 runs) with varying number of blocks/threads, but making sure that nblocks * nthreads > N. Here is what I've got (I have a nice plot but not enough reputation to post it...):

(nblocks, nthreads)                    execution time [s]          increase ratio
(196, 512)              5.0e-4            -
(391, 256)              4.8e-4            1.0
(782, 128)              4.8e-4            1.0
(1563, 64)              4.9e-4            1.0
(3125, 32)              5.0e-4            1.0
(6250, 16)              5.2e-4            1.0
(12500, 8)              9.0e-4            1.7
(25000, 4)              1.3e-3            1.4
(50000, 2)              2.3e-3            1.8

My interpretation: The GPU is divided into blocks and each block is divided into threads. Each clock cycle the GPU sends the kernel to 4 blocks (Multiprocessor count) and within each of those blocks to a warp (group of 32 threads). This implies that using a number of threads that is not a multiple of 32 is a waste of resources. As such, we can understand the general relation between (nblocks, nthreads) vs execution time. From (196, 512) to (3125, 32) the number of clock cycles taken by the GPU is roughly the same and is approximately proportional to (nblocks / 4) * (nthreads / 32). However, we roughly expect a doubling of the execution time between (3125, 32) and (6250, 16), (6250, 16) and (12500, 8) and so on.

***Why is this not the case?*** More specifically, why isn't there any significant difference in execution time between (3125, 32) and (6250, 16)?

I thank you for having taken the time to read until here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A1

When using `blocks=threads=1`, you only calculated `d[0]`, and leave `d[1...9999]` untouched. Then you will get arbitrary `sum` due to the uninitialized `d[1...9999]`.

You could initialize `d[0...9999]` with all zeros to get a constant result.

In the 3rd experiment you got `sum==30000` with `-nblocks 1 -nthreads 1` could be a coincidence that the program allocated `d[]` at the exact same space as last run, and the values in the space is unchanged. So what you get is the same result as the 2nd experiment, rather than the correct result.

### A2

Two possible reasons you may have to consider when estimating the time cost.

1. You kernel has few arithmetical operations, which make it a bandwidth bounded kernel. Number of computing threads may not be the performance bottleneck when memory access is coalesced.
2. Your data size is small. The kernel launching overhead could be too large to ignore.

Comment: A1: You were right, by "coincidence" (even though happening every time), d[] was allocated at the same space as the previous run. Initializing it corrected the result. A2: If I understand correctly, you say that you don't get a factor of 2 difference when you go from 16 threads to 8, from 8 to 4 etc... because of 1. and 2. Do you think that 1. and 2. also explain why there is no difference at all between the execution time of  (3125, 32) and that of (6250, 16)?

Comment: yes, 16 threads already reach the max bandwidth for this situation, more won't help.